# What is the difference between those two match requests that excluding a relationship type?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Assume we have node labeled `:User` that is linked to node `:Test1:Test2` (the node labeled `Test1` can also be labeled `Test2`)

```
MATCH (u:User)-->(t:Test1) WHERE NOT t:Test2 return count(distinct u); // result 10
MATCH (u:User)-->(t:Test1) WHERE NOT (u)-->(:Test2) return count(distinct u); // result 5
```

What is the difference between these two requests (except syntaxically) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WHERE in the first statement tests the endNode. In the second, it is about the existence of an connection.

The first statement only returns users that have a rel to Test1  nodes that are not Test2

The second one returns users that do have a rel to Test1, but not to Test2